# Select all customers that logged in at least three times within a time interval

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2014

I have a login table that contains the ID of the customer and the timestamp of the login time (`customerid`, `timestamp`).

I am looking to get all the customer IDs that logged in at least *three* times within *sixty* minutes. By the way, the login table is **huge**. Self joining is not an option.

For example:

```
customer id | timestamp
1           | 2016-08-16 00:00
2           | 2016-08-16 00:00
3           | 2016-08-16 00:00
1           | 2016-08-16 00:25
2           | 2016-08-16 01:25
3           | 2016-08-16 00:25
1           | 2016-08-16 00:47
2           | 2016-08-16 01:27
3           | 2016-08-16 02:25
3           | 2016-08-16 03:25
1           | 2016-08-16 01:05
```

For this example, the query should return only `customerid` 1. Any ideas?

Comment: Which RDMS / version are you on

Comment: SQL 2014 web edition

Answer (score 1):

Tested with rexTester: http://rextester.com/RMST24716 (thanks [TT.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/243373/tt)!)

```
 CREATE TABLE loginTable (id INT NOT NULL, timestamp DATETIME NOT NULL);

 INSERT INTO loginTable (id, timestamp) values 
( 1, '2016-08-16 00:00'),
( 2, '2016-08-16 00:00'),
( 3, '2016-08-16 00:00'),
( 1, '2016-08-16 00:25'),
( 2, '2016-08-16 01:25'),
( 3, '2016-08-16 00:25'),
( 1, '2016-08-16 00:47'),
( 2, '2016-08-16 01:27'),
( 3, '2016-08-16 02:25'),
( 3, '2016-08-16 03:25'),
( 1, '2016-08-16 01:05');


SELECT distinct a.id
FROM loginTable as a 
join loginTable as b on a.id = b.id and a.timestamp < b.timestamp
join loginTable as c on b.id = c.id and b.timestamp < c.timestamp
where Datediff(minute, a.timestamp, c.timestamp) <= 60;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps (http://rextester.com/CTR13554):

```
SELECT a.id, a.timestamp, COUNT(DISTINCT b.timestamp)
FROM loginTable a
JOIN loginTable b ON a.id = b.id AND a.timestamp <= b.timestamp
JOIN loginTable c ON a.id = c.id AND a.timestamp <= c.timestamp
WHERE 1=1
  AND ABS(DATEDIFF(minute,a.timestamp,b.timestamp)) <= 60
  AND ABS(DATEDIFF(minute,a.timestamp,c.timestamp)) <= 60
GROUP BY a.id, a.timestamp
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT b.timestamp) >= 3
```

btw, in your example, customer 1 logged in 3 times within an hour twice: [00:00;00:25;00:47] AND [00:25;00:47;01:05]

here the code for a quick test of the code above:

```
CREATE TABLE loginTable (id INT NOT NULL, timestamp DATETIME NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO loginTable (id, timestamp)
      SELECT 1, '2016-08-16 00:00'
UNION SELECT 2, '2016-08-16 00:00'
UNION SELECT 3, '2016-08-16 00:00'
UNION SELECT 1, '2016-08-16 00:25'
UNION SELECT 2, '2016-08-16 01:25'
UNION SELECT 3, '2016-08-16 00:25'
UNION SELECT 1, '2016-08-16 00:47'
UNION SELECT 2, '2016-08-16 01:27'
UNION SELECT 3, '2016-08-16 02:25'
UNION SELECT 3, '2016-08-16 03:25'
UNION SELECT 1, '2016-08-16 01:05'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to test only on [rextester](http://rextester.com/CBAN95345) and for mssql the following seems to work: hopefully your mssql version supports analytical functions too.

In this case,  no self joined is needed and the table is scanned only once.

```
 CREATE TABLE loginTable (id INT NOT NULL, timestamp DATETIME NOT NULL)

 INSERT INTO loginTable (id, timestamp)
       SELECT 1, '2016-08-16 00:00'
 UNION SELECT 2, '2016-08-16 00:00'
 UNION SELECT 3, '2016-08-16 00:00'
 UNION SELECT 1, '2016-08-16 00:25'
 UNION SELECT 2, '2016-08-16 01:25'
 UNION SELECT 3, '2016-08-16 00:25'
 UNION SELECT 1, '2016-08-16 00:47'
 UNION SELECT 2, '2016-08-16 01:27'
 UNION SELECT 3, '2016-08-16 02:25'
 UNION SELECT 3, '2016-08-16 03:25'
 UNION SELECT 1, '2016-08-16 01:05';

 select id,  min_t, max_t from (
 select id,
         min(timestamp) over (partition by id order by id, timestamp rows between 2 preceding and current row) as min_t, 
         max(timestamp) over (partition by id order by id, timestamp rows between 2 preceding and current row) as max_t,
         count(timestamp) over (partition by id order by id, timestamp rows between 2 preceding and current row) as num_t
   from loginTable
 ) ts_data    
  where ABS(DATEDIFF(minute,min_t,max_t)) <= 60 and num_t=3;
```

*(thanks to @Salvador to have shared some test scripts)*

**Explanation**
The idea here is to scan just once the logintable by timestamp and keep in memory for every id the last three occurrences (current included).
If the minimal timestamp and the maximum timestamp of the three happen in a 60 minutes period, we have almost the result.

Finally,  we have to manage one "corner case":
when we encounter the first or second login of a customer, we could have both the min and the max timestamp in the 60 minutes span (in cases of first login they would be the same).

However they wouldn't satisfy OP requirment (he talked of 3 distinct logins) so we have to count the number of logins and make sure they are 3 (`num_t=3`)

**Edited**
*(thanks again to @Salvador for the warning)*

There was an error in the first version where in the windows specification I said "rows between 3 preceding". Indeed I had to look at 3 rows, but the current one was included so I should have set "rows between 2 preceding".

Comment: I've never seen a query like this, I like it! but then try with this set and returns nothing: SELECT 1, '2016-08-16 00:00' UNION SELECT 2, '2016-08-16 00:00' UNION SELECT 3, '2016-08-16 00:00' UNION SELECT 1, '2016-08-16 01:25' UNION SELECT 2, '2016-08-16 01:25' UNION SELECT 3, '2016-08-16 00:25' UNION SELECT 1, '2016-08-16 01:47' UNION SELECT 2, '2016-08-16 01:27' UNION SELECT 3, '2016-08-16 02:25' UNION SELECT 3, '2016-08-16 03:25' UNION SELECT 1, '2016-08-16 02:05' UNION SELECT 1, '2016-08-16 02:20'

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I've done a mistake in the window specification. I've edited the query to correct the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using self-join

```
    SELECT M.customer_id FROM (
    SELECT Distinct   T1.customer_id, T1.Time,
    T2.Time,
    Datediff(minute,T1.Time,T2.Time) as diff
    FROM Table T1 JOIN Table T2 ON T1.customer_id=T2.customer_id
    AND T1.Time<T2.Time
    ) M
    WHERE diff<=60
    Group By M.customer_id
    Having count(M.*)>=3
```

Comment: Wouldn't this return a customer who hits the site twice a day over the course of three separate days?

Answer (score 0):

This query gets customerids who logged in at least three times within 60 minutes from NOW:

```
SELECT customerid FROM 
(SELECT customerid, count(*) as loginnumber FROM LoginTable
 GROUP BY customerid
 WHERE [timestamp] > DATEADD(minute, -60, GetDate()) ) LT
WHERE loginnumber >= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I adapted my Pqsql solution to mssql: 
you can see the result here http://rextester.com/CBPW42897

```
WITH tbl AS (
  SELECT id 
    , IIF( DATEDIFF(minute, 
                    lag(ts, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ts asc ), 
                    ts )<=60, 
           1, 0) as freq60
  FROM loginTable
)
SELECT id FROM tbl
  GROUP BY tbl.id HAVING SUM(freq60) >=3
  ORDER BY tbl.id
```

I like MSSQL's handy functions IIF and DATEDIFF, but its a bit awkward to specified the same window every time.

The following code works in PgSQL,

```
with tbl as (
  select cust_id 
    ,case when extract(epoch from (ts - lag(ts, 1) over w) ) < 3600 then 1 
          else 0
     end as freq60
  from loginTable
  window w as (partition by id order by ts asc ) 
)
select cust_id 
from tbl
  group by tbl.cust_id having sum(freq60) >=3
  order by tbl.cust_id
```

The idea is pretty straightforward. Create a window frame by customer id, sorted member rows by time. let each row's timestamp minus its previous row's timestamp to get the interval, if interval within 60m, return 1, else 0, then do aggregation on the result. return the id whose freq >= 3
There's only one time sort, done within the window function. faster by orders of magnitude than self-join when dealing with tens of thousands of records.

```
id  freq60  prev_ts ts  intval
1   0   null    2016-08-16 00:00:00 
1   1   2016-08-16 00:00:00 2016-08-16 00:25:00 25
1   1   2016-08-16 00:25:00 2016-08-16 00:47:00 22
1   1   2016-08-16 00:47:00 2016-08-16 01:05:00 18
```

Comment: Looks like the OP mentioned SQL Server in comments.

Comment: Yeah, I know. So I just assuming he can replicate the same behavior in MS SQL easily ? Actually MySQL is not good at this either, I ended up migrating to Postgresql for this. Their WINDOW function made such related analysis a lot easier.

Comment: The SQL dialect of SQL Server is sufficiently different from MySQL that it won't be easily ported.

Comment: Probably a solution based on Postgresql WINDOW could be more easily migrated

Answer (score 0):

an easy way to find the ones which don't span hour boundaries is:

```
select
  id,
  datepart(yy,timestamp) as yy,
  datepart(mm,timestamp) as mm,
  datepart(dd,timestamp) as dd,
  datepart(hh,timestamp) as hh,
  count(*)
from
  logintable
group by
  id,
  datepart(yy,timestamp),
  datepart(mm,timestamp),
  datepart(dd,timestamp),
  datepart(hh,timestamp)
having
  count(*) >= 3
```

if your table is very large, you might knock it down to clients with at least three logins per day, and then self-join.  It will still miss logins across day spans, but it's a simple solution that moves you forward while you work on a more sophisticated one.